# Read from Sybase Database and write to Postgres SQL

Tags: spring-batch

I need assistance in knowing whether Spring Batch is correct way of implementing a functionality in which I want to read a table from Sybase and then convert / transform it to the target persistence and write that POJO in the Postgres sql.

I have tried implementing it but not sure while constructing the batch in its repository which datasource to be given. I have only read access to source system.

WHen I wrote different configuration for Sybase and Postgres and given Postgres repository datasource in the Job repository, it gives me error that datasource is already bind to a thread.

I am also using JPA to query/update database unit.

I tired implementing spring batch but when I gave the postgres datasource to job repository it gives me error.